# Robot Framework not detecting subdirectories

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'm having an issue with robotframework not loading classes in a specific directory. My layout is as follows:

```
Dir1
  class1
  class2
Dir2
  class3
  class4
Dir3
  class5
class6
test.robot
```

So dir1-3, class6 and test.robot files are all in the same root directory. When I run my test.robot script, its supposed to call a class and function, class3 in dir2. However, when it gets to that step, it gets a "key not found" error. I tried changing the code to use a function in class1 dir1, and that worked no problem. The files are almost exactly the same (selenium automation classes that are all linked through class6).

Now, my code is all in python. I removed all the .pyc files from all directories then ran the robot script again. Upon running the robot script, all of the .pyc files were recreated with the exception of those classes in Dir2. So I can conclude that the script is not going into that directory for some reason, and I cant figure out why. Here is what my robot script looks like:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLib

*** Test Cases ***
Database Download
    Class6.init_class
    Class6.function1
    Class5.function2
    Class3.function3
```

Note that SeleniumLib is the name of the "root" directory. Upon execution, the init_class (basically a manual constructor) executes, then function1. All other classes extend class6, so class5 and 3 are both extensions of 6. Calling function2 worked, but calling function3 results in a no keyword found error.

I'm running the latest version of robot and selenium (3.0 and 2.5.6 respectively)

Comment: Most of the people don't use Selenium anymore. We use Selenium2Library (basically, it extends the deprecated lib and has much more improvements). Would you benefit if using Selenium2Library, doing a migrated copy of your project?

Comment: @Helio we are (thankfully) getting rid of robotframework within the next few weeks. This bit of code I have is hopefully the last time I will need to mess with it. We need it to function, however, for at least a few more weeks while we continue testing this software. So Selenium2Library will not be an option for us.

Comment: Too bad you have had a bad experience with robotframework. Good luck in finding help for selenium core.